# Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.util.VisibleForTesting

Tags: class, gradle, google-analytics, jar, duplicates

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.util.VisibleForTesting
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0) and
>   libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar (libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Comment: How did you fixed this error?

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle project file then update it to :
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

Or go to '**Refactor**' menu then click on '**Migrate to AndroidX**'